# datafile or Tablespace use information

Tags: oracle11g, tablespace

Without creating a trigger, are there any V$ views that show when either a Tablespace or datafile was last accessed or used?

Give you an idea of why... I'm looking to do some reorg and would be nice to know if I can take that particular object or tbs offline.

Comment: http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/server.111/b28310/tspaces014.htm#ADMIN11410

Answer (score 0):

DBA_HIST_SEG_STAT records the number of reads per tablespace per snapshot.  The DBA_HIST_ tables are only periodically refreshed, normally once per hour.  To retrieve the latest data, a very similar query using V$SEGMENT_STATISTICS would need to be UNIONed to the query below.

Finding the information per data file is trickier.  That information is in DBA_HIST_ACTIVE_SESS_HISTORY, usually in the column P1 when P1TEXT = 'file#'.  But that information is only a sample, it's very possible a single read to a data file would not be captured.

Note that using the DBA_HIST_ tables requires the Configuration Pack license.

```
select name, begin_interval_time, end_interval_time, sum(logical_reads_delta)
from dba_hist_seg_stat
join dba_hist_snapshot using (snap_id, dbid, instance_number)
join v$tablespace using (ts#)
group by v$tablespace.name, begin_interval_time, end_interval_time
having sum(logical_reads_delta) > 0
order by v$tablespace.name, begin_interval_time desc
```